# Dynamic MYSQL Pivot table script not working in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pivot, pivot-table

I have this code that generates a dynamic PIVOT table that works well in phpmyadmin, but It is not working in a PHP script?
How Can I make it work in a PHP script

```
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            
          'MAX(IF(subjects.subject_name = ''',
      subject_name,
      ''', term_averages.student_average, NULL)) AS ',
      replace(subjects.subject_name, ' ', '')
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    from subjects;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT 
 student_subject_averages.student_id,
        grades.grade_name,
        users.id as learner_id,
        users.name,
        users.middlename,
        users.lastname,
        term_averages.student_average,
        CASE WHEN term_averages.number_of_passed_subjects>=5  AND term_averages.student_average>=50 THEN "Passed" ELSE "Failed" END AS "remark",
      
', @sql,'
  FROM student_subject_averages INNER JOIN teaching_loads ON teaching_loads.id=student_subject_averages.teaching_load_id
        INNER JOIN subjects ON teaching_loads.subject_id=subjects.id
        INNER JOIN users ON users.id=student_subject_averages.student_id
        INNER JOIN grades_students ON grades_students.student_id=student_subject_averages.student_id
        INNER JOIN grades ON grades_students.grade_id=grades.id
        INNER JOIN term_averages ON term_averages.student_id=student_subject_averages.student_id
        WHERE grades.stream_id=1 AND student_subject_averages.term_id=4 AND term_averages.term_id=4 
        GROUP BY student_subject_averages.student_id  
        ORDER BY term_averages.student_average DESC');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

how can run the above mysql script in PHP ?

Comment: You can't execute those statements from PHP, they have to be in a stored procedure. You can call the stored procedure from PHP just like any other query.

Comment: @Barmar, You don't have to use a procedure. You _can_ run `SET` and `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` statements as SQL using `query()`. It's just not necessary, because you can store the query in a PHP string variable, and the MySQL extension has functions for `prepare()` and `execute()`.

Comment: For starters, get your php code to execute one SQL statement at a time. Don't just shove that multi statement hunk of SQL into a single `execute()` call.

Comment: @BillKarwin, thanks, how can I implement it in the way you have outlined?

Comment: Check out my stored proc:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot